# InMemoryUploadedFile to binary string in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I need to send file as BinaryData string to some API. Example

```
files = request.FILES
for file in files.values():
    requests.post(
        url='some_url',
        headers={
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token)
        },
        json={
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "type": "identity_assurance.document_verification.americas.us.drivers_license.image.back",
                    "value": {
                        "$objectType": "BinaryData",
                        "data": file.read(),
                        "metadata": {
                            "cropped": False
                        },
                        "mime_type": "image/png"
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    )
```

But I got `TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable` on file.read(). In `data` field should be byte string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
b64encode(file.read()).decode('utf-8')
```

after that it will be json serializable

Answer (score 1):

If you run `type(file.read())` will return bytes string with type `<class 'bytes'>` and the requests lib needs string type for json serialize.

Try something like: `file.read().decode()` or `file.read().decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: same error TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable